# Laravel pagination appends with array filtering

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code to that works ok on the first page showing the right number of paginated pages, but clicking on the second page shows no results. What might be wrong here

```
$category = Input::get('maincat', []);
$locate = Input::get('location');


      $list = Buy::with('catbuy');

    $this['requests'] = $list
     ->whereHas('catbuy', function($q) use ($category){
        $q->whereIn('id', $category);
    })
    ->where('location', 'like', '%' . $locate  . '%')

    ->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(1)->appends(['location' => $locate, $category]);
```

Comment: On which route you are calling this code?

Comment: ````appends(Input::all());```` soloved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`appends(Input::all());` solved it.

*(question was answered in the comments)*